# How to truncate each line of a text object in Crystal after a specified number of characters

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports, I have a single text field (from SQL) in which users input multiple sentences. Each sentence is separated by pressing the enter key.

On the report, I have set the CanGrow property to unlimited, however, I want each sentence to truncate after 50 characters, and have the next line begin with the start of the next sentence.

**EXAMPLE:**

*User's input is as follows:*

```
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve
thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen
twenty twenty-one twenty-two twenty-three twenty-four twenty-five
twenty-six twenty-seven
```

*Desired report output:*

```
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten e
thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighte
twenty twenty-one twenty-two twenty-three twenty-f
twenty-six twenty-seven
```

I have only had luck getting the report to either:
a) wrap the text to a new line (not desired)
b) shrink the size of the text to make it smaller (not desired)

Help getting this to truncate after 50 characters would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: This is not Tested Solution
```

Typical problem but try some thing like this:

```
Local NumberVar i:=0;
Local StringVar j;
While i <= Length(<<DatabaseString>>) Do
(
j:=j+Mid(<<DatabaseString>>, i, 50) +chrw(13);
i:=i+50;
);
j
```

Option 2:

```
Mid(<<DatabaseString>>, 1, 50) +chrw(13)+Mid(<<DatabaseString>>, 51, 50) +chrw(13); //Continue till the length of the string
```

Let me know how it goes.